# Serialize Ontology Reasoner Results with OWL API for web site

Tags: serialization, ontology, owl

I would like to generate inferences over an ontology with the OWL API or directly with something like the Hermit reasoner.   That is easy (code shown below).  However, I would like to cache / store / save those results so that I don't have to rerun the reasoner each time.   This is what happens in the VM.  The first time I call this:

```
Set<OWLClass> classes = reasoner.getSubClasses(parent, false).getFlattened();
```

it takes about 20 seconds (in this example).  The second time it takes no time to generate the same results because they're cached.    That is great.  However, if I bounce my VM I have to re-run the reasoner (I have some fairly long queries) or save the output to a database to display them in right away.

Reasoner is not serializable (either from Hermit, or via the OWL API) and there seems to be no obvious way to me to recreate a Reasoner and load any previous results into it.  They have to be recalculated each time.

Serializing the ontology is straightforward, but I don't see any way 
of reloading results into the reasoner to save you from having to make 
the same calls again.

Is there something I'm missing?    Would Jena be a better choice for this?

```java
OWLOntologyManager owlOntologyManager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); 
File file = new File("resource/RDFData/release", "NEMOv2.85_GAFLP1_diffwave_data.rdf"); 
IRI iri = IRI.create(file); 
OWLDataFactory factory = owlOntologyManager.getOWLDataFactory(); 
OWLOntology owlOntology = owlOntologyManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(iri); 
Reasoner reasoner = new Reasoner(owlOntology); 
OWLClass parent = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(DataSet.NS + "#NEMO_0877000")); 
Set<OWLClass> classes = reasoner.getSubClasses(parent, false).getFlattened(); 

FileOutputStream fos = null; 
ObjectOutputStream out = null; 
try { 
    fos = new FileOutputStream("reasoner.ser"); 
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 
    out.writeObject(reasoner); 
    out.close(); 
} catch (IOException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: The answer is to export your OWL ontologies with the inferred ontology.  After reading in the new inferred ontology and creating a reasoner with it, the reasoner does not feel the need to re-infer.  Follow the export described here:

http://owlapi.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/owlapi/owl1_1/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Example11.java?view=markup

and then reimport:  
    OWLOntology readOntology = owlOntologyManager.loadOntology(iriOut);
    Reasoner r2 = new Reasoner(readOntology);
    classes = r2.getSubClasses(parent, false).getFlattened();

Answer (score 0):

Saving the inferred ontology (which you obtained from the InferredOntologyGenerator) seems to be the best method.

From what I understand though, the reasoner will still check for consistency and classify the ontology when you create a new reasoner, but it's just faster because you have made all the inferences explicit.